# How can I get the certain data from autonumber id using a SQL select statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

**PROBLEM:**

How can I get the certain `autonumber id`?

```
ID  DESCRIPTION CLASS 
 1  test1         a 
 2  test2         b
 3  test3         a
 4  test4         a 
 5  test5         b
```

`id` (auto-increment in SQL Server)

**Here is the scenario:**

I have here 3 columns something like this.

My class is declared using this to get the value of a certain class.

```
string strclass = string.empty;
strclass = request.querystring["Class"];
```

How can I get the id of `test2`?

I would like to use this `select` statement wherein I will just use the variable.

For example:

```
string sqltest = "select description from items where class = '" + strID + "' and class = '" strclass "'";
```

I just really don't know, how will I get the class `id`.

Comment: Why do you pass the class as url-parameter when you actually need the id?

Comment: what i really do is to update the records. If i have the same class type. then it will just update all the records with the  class type "a". that's why i need to get the id which is auto-increment.

Comment: or is there's any other way where i can get the data? please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question really is very confusing. You want the id but your SQL returns the description. Surely your SQL should just be:

```
string sqltest = "select id from items where description = @description and class = @class";
```

Do not use string concatenation to generate SQL strings as that opens you up to SQL injection attacks.